"User hasn't approved this consumer" JWT flow from ConnectedApp in a different org
From my understanding, having the JWT Authorization flow can have a centralized "ConnectedApp" that's on the main org (named Org A), and you can install the "metadata" of this ConnectedApp onto a different org (named Org B) by packaging it in with the original 2GP that has the main codebase to be able to connect to it.
Example of the .xml metadata file
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ConnectedApp xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
      <developerName>'namespace'__'ConnectedAppDeveloperName'</developerName>
      <label>'ConnectedAppLabel'</label>
      <version>4.0</version>
    </ConnectedApp>

I've got two of them, one for sandboxes (test.salesforce.com) and another for prod (login.salesforce.com)
I've got that all setup, the ConnectedApp "metadata" correctly is packaged with my main package, and that installs correctly into Org B. I've also made sure through JWT.io that the flow works correctly by using an account from the main org (Org A).
Now the issue comes from when trying to perform the JWT flow from the Org B, that's got the full package together installed. My only assumption is that there's an extra step needed that properly links Org B to Org A, but I can't find any additional information.
I've already got:


Admin approved users are pre-authorized, both on Org A and Org B



Made sure that System Admin Profile is pre-authorized, both on Org A and Org B


IP Relaxation is selected.


Take a look at External Client App - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_apps_and_external_client_apps_features.htm&type=5

@identigral thanks for that actually, ECA seems to be way more modern than ConnectedApps, and helped clear up my issues once I migrated to it!

Using an External Client App was the way to go and it now works correctly on Org B. Way more modern, the packaging process was streamlined very nicely, and offered way less headaches.
Here's a video by the Salesforce team with an explanation and demo on the matter.
Also, I had to create my ECA in my Partner Org, and not from a Sandbox, Dev Org or Scratch Org, otherwise it wouldn't work.
